# Jest gives an error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token export" for node_modules\@microsoft\mgt-react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, node-modules, babel-jest

I am using jest to test my react App. While running the test for one component which uses **node_modules@microsoft\mgt-react**  which is a typescript module, I am getting the below error.

```
 export * from './Mgt';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I tried adding transformIgnorePatterns, but it is not working.

my babel.config.js looks like this.

```
 module.exports = {
   presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
   plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"],
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I solved it by stubbing the component I was using.

For example, I'm using the PeoplePicker in one of my files:

```js
import { PeoplePicker as MgtPeoplePicker } from '@microsoft/mgt-react';

const PeoplePicker = () => {
  return (
    // something
  );
};
```

I created a file where I mock its implementation:

```js
// __mocks__/mgt-react.js
export default class PeoplePicker {
    // purposely empty
}
```

Then, in my `package.json` I added the following:

```json
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@microsoft/mgt-react": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/mgt-react.js",
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding it on my `jest.config.js` but it didn't work.